# How do i add up my array values and display it along side with my other values

Tags: c++

I am trying to add up all the values that have been stored into array b and have it display under the "total column" and don't know how to only have the scores add together.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int array[5][4];
    int sum = 0;
    cout<<"Enter grades for 4 exams for the 5 students \n";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int b=1;b<=4;b++)
        {
            cout <<setw(8)<< "enter student "<< i << "'s grade for exam " << b << '\n';
            cin >> array[i][b];
        }
    }

    cout <<"ID"<<setw(11)<<"score 1"<<setw(11)<<"score 2"<<setw(11)<<"score 3"<<setw(11)<<"score 4"<<setw(11)<<"total"<<setw(11)<<"letter"<<endl;
    cout <<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout << i<< "  ";
        for(int b=1;b<=4;b++)
        {   
            sum = sum + array[b];
            cout <<setw(10)<<array[i][b]<<sum;
            
        }
        cout <<'\n';
    }
    cout <<"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

To be more specific around line 28

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cout << i<< "  ";
        for(int b=1;b<=4;b++)
        {   
            sum = sum + array[b];
            cout <<setw(10)<<array[i][b]<<sum;
            
        }
        cout <<'\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays indexes start at 0, not 1. You are correctly looping through your array's 1st dimension, but not its 2nd dimension. You need to change the inner `for` loops from `for(int b=1;b<=4;b++)` to `for(int b=0;b<4;b++)`

Also, to handle the `total` column, you simply need to reset `sum` to 0 on each iteration of the 1st dimension, and then print the result after the iteration of the 2nd dimension.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[5][4];

    cout << "Enter grades for 4 exams for the 5 students \n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < 4; b++)
        {
            cout << "Enter student " << i+1 << "'s grade for exam " << b+1 << '\n';
            cin >> array[i][b];
        }
    }

    cout << "ID" << setw(11) << "score 1" << setw(11) << "score 2" << setw(11) << "score 3" << setw(11) << "score 4" << setw(11) << "total" << setw(11) << "letter" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << left << i+1 << right;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int b = 0; b < 4; b++)
        {   
            sum = sum + array[i][b];
            cout << setw(11) << array[i][b];
            
        }
        cout << setw(11) << sum << '\n';
    }
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Yy75rR)